# InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python: "Cannot evaluate Select". Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

have this error when try run this code:

```
query = delete(BannerLocalization).where(
        BannerLocalization.locale == locale,
        BannerLocalization.id == pk,
        BannerLocalization.banner_id.in_(
            select(
                Banner.id
            ).join(
                BannerLocalization
            ).where(
                BannerLocalization.locale == locale,
                BannerLocalization.id == pk,
                Banner.banner_type == BannerTypesEnum.EVENT
            )
        )
    )
```

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not evaluate current criteria in Python: "Cannot evaluate Select". Specify 'fetch' or False for the synchronize_session execution option.

Does somebody know what is wrong?

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/q/51221686/5320906

Answer (score 10):

I've resolves this problem:

Set `execution_options=immutabledict({"synchronize_session": 'fetch'})`
to `session.execute`

Working variant looks like this:

````
await session.execute(query, execution_options=immutabledict({"synchronize_session": 'fetch'}))```
````

Comment: I imported it like this: `from sqlalchemy.util._collections import immutabledict`

Comment: I found that a regular dictionary worked too -- no need for the immutabledict.


[SQLAlchemy Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#orm-expression-update-delete) has some discussion about the `synchronize_session` strategies.