# What does synchronize_session mean in sqlalchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I was reading the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_basics.html#orm-expression-update-delete) of sqlalchemy and I am wondering what synchronize_session does. The example given for the delete function in the Query API was:

```
session.query(User).filter(User.name == "squidward").\
    delete(synchronize_session="fetch")
```

However, I did not understand what synchronizing the session means and there was no explanation for this term.

I am not very familiar with databases so it could be due to my lack of knowledge in this aspect. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51222378/5320906) may help

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks that helps! Could you check if my understanding is correct? Let's say the database has a row with `id == 1` whereas the session is not updated and does not contain the row with `id == 1`. If I attempt to delete the row with `id == 1` using `delete(synchronize_session=False)`, the row wouldn't be deleted in the database even if I call `session.commit()` right? Since the session is not synchronized with the database

Comment: @GordThompson It was the same link given as @snakecharmerb and it helps me understand it better but I just wanted to check if my understanding is correct since the link only talks about `update()` and I am still a little unsure about `delete()`.